# Shortest path on graph with changing weights

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I was trying to solve a local programming contest question. The problem is basically about finding the shortest path in a weighted graph. I am pretty new to these types of problems and I thought I could use Dijkstra's algorithm. However, there is a small complication - certain values are different, depending on the situation of this current path.

**Problem**

There are two types of weights: normal weights and weights with condition (let's call them K). The condition is this: once you move through edge with weight K, all other weights of type K have value of 0. This brings a few more problems, because the apparent shortest path can be beaten by a combination of edges with weights of type K.

**Example**

Below is this type of problem. If no weights would change their value, we could find the shortest path easily with Dijkstra. However, when weights K change their value, we can find a shorter path, because the weight of the edge C-D is 0 after moving through the edge A-C.
[image]

**Question**

How can I find the shortest path?

Can I use Dijkstra's algorithm here or is it better to use another algorithm like A* or BFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many K's are there?

I it's only one, Dijkstra is good.
I will add to say that BFS does not handle weighs well.

Reminder: Dijkstra finds the shortest path from a vertex to all vertexes.

Run Dijkstra twice and define a different wight function for each run. First the wight function for K values is infinite. Second wight function for K values is 0.

Than compare the result from run1 to run2+K.

This is true because if the shortest path is without K first run will find it. otherwise it's with K and the second run will find it. Either way the algorithm will find it.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Number of K edges is in the range between 0 and the number of edges, but your solution seems to work no matter how many K edges are in the graph.

Comment: This not what I ment by how many K's are there. Imagine you have M values also...or Z values also. So for each different value you will have to do work more. The number of K edges does not matter

Comment: Oh, ok I get it now. So with more special values (K, M or any other) there are more combinations of possible paths.